# I can't delete a branch with "-d" only with "--delete"

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I'm a beginner and doing some tests with branch creation and deletion:

```
git checkout -b quick-test
Switched to a new branch 'quick-test'

git branch
  main
* quick-test
  –d

git checkout -d quick-test
HEAD is now at 4df2fe6 Merge pull request #1 from tadm123/feature-readme-instructions

git branch
* (HEAD detached at refs/heads/quick-test)
  main
  quick-test
  –d
```

The only way it works is to use the full command `--delete`:

```
git branch --delete quick-test
Deleted branch quick-test (was 4df2fe6).

git branch
* (HEAD detached at 4df2fe6)
  main
  –d
```

Any advise into what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated

Comment: You are using `git checkout -d`, but `git branch --delete`. These are different commands (checkout vs branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a branch, use `git branch -d`. To create a branch and check out, use `git checkout -b`. `git checkout -d` *detaches* your HEAD, effectively checking out a commit directly without being on a branch, it does not delete a branch.

> ##### [`-d, --detach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--d)
>
> Rather than checking out a branch to work on it, check out a commit
> for inspection and discardable experiments. This is the default
> behavior of `git checkout <commit>` when `<commit>` is not a branch
> name. See the "DETACHED HEAD" section below for details.

If you look at your `git branch` output, you have a branch named "–d" (looks very similar to "-d"). Delete it to avoid any future confusion and problems (`git branch -d –d`).

To delete branch `quick-test`: `git branch -d quick-test`.

Comment: OP's branch is *not* named `-d` but `–d`, though :-)

Comment: @RomainValeri good catch! That explains why I'm unable to create such a branch :)

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**
`git branch -d <branch>` and `git branch --delete <branch>` are both fine.

---

**So what happened?**

When you first tried to delete `quick-test`, you used (probably by mistake) the `–` character (en dash) instead of the regular hyphen (`-`).

git considers it a normal character and does not detect your (intended) `-d` option, creating a `–d` branch instead!

---

**How to recover?**

Delete the useless branch with

```
git branch -d –d
```

then make sure your interface or anything else isn't silently replacing your hyphens.